# How to pass information from one controller to another using "UserDefaults.standard.set( )"

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am trying to pass the information from one controller to another controller. I have two controllers 1.ViewController 2.SecondController. I want to pass information from ViewController to SecondController using UserDefaults.standard.set where i am trying to get the reference of viewController but i am encountering error saying "assigning non-property list object for key value "controller". Below is the code. Please help me

```
      let defaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(self, forKey: "controller")
        defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: `UserDefaults` should not be used to pass data. Just set an appropriate property that you have defined on your view controller.

Comment: And you do not need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers). Previous comments are correct, you should not be using UserDefaults to pass data between controllers. The 'Apple way' is to use a segue. See the provided link for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In **SecondController** declare variable as

```
  var firstVC: ViewController?
```

then in **ViewController** assign **self** to **firstVC** while pushing to **SecondController** like:

```
  secondVC.firstVC = self
```